# Chrome issue with video iframe responsive sizes broke website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have this page - http://tomaspetrecek.cz. We have youtube embeded videos at posts via iframe which is wrapped with DIV container. Just like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) has.

But in Chrome is website weird, sidebar menu lagging with website background. Only in Chrome, only on homepage.

I found out, when I removed css width/height from iframe of youtube video, page will be ok.

I tried to remove scripts by scripts to solve this issue, but there is some bad combination maybe. I tried to use different div with non youtube iframe and it is working correctly, this issue shows only when iframe's content is html5 youtube player.

HTML of video responsive container looks:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Yjtt5bdLPHk" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
```

and CSS looks:

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px; 
    margin: 10px 25px;
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container > iframe,
.video-container > object,
.video-container > embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

PS: Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: Same thing using Opera or any webkit browser

Comment: I tried with Safari on mac, and it's OK. I see this bug only on chrome (windows 7, mac os). Opera on windows looks good.